# Talk to Signal-R blazor server with python request

Tags: python, python-requests, blazor, signalr, blazor-webassembly

There is a website designed by blazor tech, it doesn't offer REST API services that makes me able to send reqular HTTP request. but i need to talk to server with python (like a robot)  and send HTTP request to perform something. if the website was designed with REST-API Json (client talks to server with regular HTTP requests with ajax-json) it was easy to sniff the network to see what fields and values are being sent in each request. but in blazor when i sniff the network, the data is binary and somehow unreadable for me. is it possible to talk to blazor server with python?

what i understood is the negotiation between server and client is:

```
Request URL: http://the-website.com/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1

Server:
{"negotiateVersion":1,"connectionId":"BQo88a7QEbaIlf-5xualRQ","connectionToken":"vjAHs-    6RprY07lfIba2goQ","availableTransports":[{"transport":"ServerSentEvents","transferFormats":["Text"]},{"transport":"LongPolling","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]}]}

after that. the data is like:
  d����JS.BeginInvokeJS��)Blazor._internal.attachWebRendererInterop�[0,{"__dotNetObject":1},{},{}]
```

If i realize how can i send HTTP request to blazor server with python, my problem would be resolved